# The reduction formula for this or if it is possible to solve this integral further in terms of n?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, reduction-formula

> If $$I_n=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\sin^2\frac{nx}{2}}{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}\,dx$$ for $n\in \Bbb Z$.

My attempt: I first plugged $\frac{x}{2}$ as t and then converted the whole integral according to the assumed substitution. Then as the function is even, so I changed the limits of the integral from (-$\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$) to (0 and $\frac{\pi}{2}$), so finally got a simpler form of this integral $$4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin ^2({nt})}{\sin^2{t}}\,dt.$$
Then I changed the variable to x ($4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^2 ({nx})}{\sin^2{x}}\,dx$).
But after this stage, I am not able to proceed further. Neither I am able to solve this with integration by parts nor any further appropriate substitution.

> The answer key states that $I_1, I_2,I_3....I_n $ forms an A.P.

I am even getting this answer by plugging the respective values of n directly into integral.

1. But is it correct to directly plug in the values of n and solve?
2. Is there any way by which we can simplify the given integral to a final form?
3. Or can we use reduction formula to prove it is an A.P

Comment: Can you tell us what $W$ is?

Comment: @Maths the more widely accepted notation for the set of integers (whole numbers) is $\Bbb Z$ (written \Bbb Z is mathjax) from the German word Zahlen

Comment: For $n=1$ you have $I_1=2\pi$.  For larger $n$, can you use the angle sum formula to write the numerator in terms of smaller angles (say, $(n-1)x$ and $x$)?

Comment: And whole numbers are $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: You don't actually need to separate the variables within $$ repeatedly, also we don't have a standard notation W for whole numbers. I guess you wanted to mean $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$

Comment: @mjqxxxx, I even tried to do that, but it does not prove helpful, it adds an extra term again which is very tough to integrate.

Comment: @RhysHughes Usually, whole numbers are positive integers, maybe including $0,$ I forget the usual case there.

Comment: $$\frac{\sin nt}{\sin t}=U_{n-1}(\cos t)$$ here $U_{n-1}$ is the Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind. Not sure how that helps. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, Having little knowledge, I don't know how to proceed with Chebyshev Polynomials, it would be great if you explain a bit more as it is clearly replacing the integral.

Comment: I think with the chebyshev polynomial too, we have to plug in n values directly to integral, and that's where I am confused. Is it correct to directly plug into the integral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I_n=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin^2 (nx/2)}{\sin^2 (x/2)} dx = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1-\cos nx}{\sin^2(x/2)} dx$$
Take $$I_{n+1}-I_n=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\cos(n+1)x-\cos nx}{\sin ^2(x/2)}=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{2\sin(n+1/2)x}{\sin(x/2)}dx=J_n$$
Next $$J_{n+1}-J_n=2\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(n+1)x~dx=0.$$
Hence, $J_n$ is independent of of $n$, we have $J_n=J_0=2\pi$. This means that $I_n$ form an AP with common difference of $2\pi$, where $I_0=0$. Finally we get $I_n=2n\pi$

Comment: @Z Ahmed, Thank You Very Much. Really a wonderful solution.

Comment: You’ve got two sign errors that cancel out. $$(1-\cos(n+1)x)-(1-\cos nx)=\cos nx-\cos(n+1)x,$$ and $$\cos(n+1)x-\cos(nx)=\color{red}{-}\sin\left(n+\frac1{2}\right)x\sin\frac x2$$ Don’t forget the minus sign.

Comment: Anyway, +1. One way to remember that sign in the case $f(x)=\cos(n+1)x-\cos(nx)$ is that for small $y>0,$  $\cos y$ is decreasing, so $f(x)<0$when $x>0$ is small.